# 2D faux gravity in unity (C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gravity

Im working on a project which uses 2D gravity. The setting is in space where you shoot projectiles, and if they are close enough to a planet, the gravity of the planet attracts the projectile. The projectile uses colliders and force applied to the Rigidbody2d when fired.

This image I found explains it well:

[image]

I had some code which works, but is not perfect. Its kinda weird in a way that it seems some parts attract the projectile harder than other parts. Some of the times, when i shoot my projectile past the object, instead of getting attracted to the object, it suddenly speeds past it. Here is the code:

```
public class Gravity : MonoBehaviour{

public GameObject planet;
public float maxGravity;
public float maxGravityDist;
public Vector3 force;

public Rigidbody2D rb;

void Update(){
    
    float dist = Vector2.Distance(planet.transform.position, transform.position);
    Vector3 v = planet.transform.position - transform.position;

    force = v.normalized * (1.0f - dist / maxGravityDist) * maxGravity;
    rb.AddForce(v.normalized * (1.0f - dist / maxGravityDist) * maxGravity);
}
}
```

Comment: It's not totally clear what your question is?

Comment: I would like to add this gravity mechanic to my game, as shown in the picture. The code I already have somewhat does it, but not perfectly. Just want to know if there are some changes I need to make to the code or if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: N-body algorithm ?